# Send multiple broadcast to multiple listeners

Tags: concurrency, go

I want to send multiple broadcast to multiple listeners in go.

I can't send data through a channel, because only one listener will get it, except for the `close` signal (second "*multiple*" of my title).

However once a channel is closed, I can't send any other signal (first "*multiple*" of my title).

Hence I wrote the following code (explanation at the end of this post):

```
package main

import "sync"

// Broadcast allows to send a signal to all listeners
type Broadcast struct {
    lock sync.RWMutex
    ch   chan struct{}
}

// NewBroadcast creates a new broadcast
func NewBroadcast() *Broadcast {
    return &Broadcast{
        lock: sync.RWMutex{},
        ch:   make(chan struct{}),
    }
}

// Receive a channel on which the next (close) signal will be sent
func (b *Broadcast) Receive() <-chan struct{} {
    b.lock.RLock()
    defer b.lock.RUnlock()
    return b.ch
}

// Send a signal to all listeners
func (b *Broadcast) Send() {
    b.lock.Lock()
    defer b.lock.Unlock()
    close(b.ch)
    b.ch = make(chan struct{})
}
```

Usage example:

```
func main() {

    b := NewBroadcast()

    done := make(chan bool)
    quit := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        <-b.Receive()
        done <- true
    }()

    go func() {
        <-b.Receive()
        <-b.Receive()
        <-b.Receive()
        <-b.Receive()
        done <- true
    }()

    go func() {
        <-done
        <-done
        close(done)
        close(quit)
    }()

    func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                return
            case <-time.After(1 * time.Millisecond):
                b.Send()
            }
        }
    }()

}
```

I simply close the "current" channel to send a broadcast to all listeners and I create a new channel for the next `Send`. A `ReadWriteMutex` is added to prevent concurrency issues.

I would appreciate any comment regarding the code, the style and anything else!

Comment: Code looks fine, just the last `func` doesn't need to be a function, you can do that directly in `main`. Instead of using an empty `struct`, it's more common to use and empty `interface` as a placeholder. Also see [this](https://github.com/tjgq/broadcast/blob/master/broadcast.go) somewhat more efficient implementation. It creates one channel per listener, and when sending, simply sends data to all channels. Seems more natural to me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The last `func` is here to allow to `return` from inside the `select` (as a `break` will only break the `select` and not the `for` loop). My code is simpler than your link, because I don't need to send data to the listeners (the signal is enough). Since I have much less logic, my code should actually be more efficient (it also has fewer functionalities)

Comment: And according to an [answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22770744/3207406), using a `struct{}` is more memory efficient than an `interface{}` (but doesn't allow to store any data - which I don't need)

Comment: In that case your approach is good enough, but still, creating a new channel on every `send` and using your own mutexes instead of channels' internal synchronization... Seems like a not-so-elegant abuse of the `close` mechanism.

Comment: If you have a more elegant suggestion, I would be happy to see it! I use the `close` mechanism so that I don't have to care about slow listeners (the example you linked may block the broadcaster if the channel of a listener is full)

Comment: So be it. But then you might very well get [deadlocked](http://rextester.com/EWNU53406) in the case of slow readers.

Comment: @kyrill: the deadlock is not caused by the implementation, but rather by the usage of the broadcast. If you wait for a broadcast that was sent before you started listening, it is normal that you wait forever.

Answer (score 6):

### Concept

The basic concept of having a channel that you hand out to all receivers, and then close that channel as a signal, is a good one. The way you use that concept in your example usage, is a bit contrived, and I don't think it represents a real use-case, but it's good enough for an idea of how it could be used.

### Communication

In Go, the best practice is to use "communication" over "locks". This is documented in [the `sync` package](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) as:

> Other than the Once and WaitGroup types, most are intended for use by low-level library routines. Higher-level synchronization is better done via channels and communication.

In your code, what does this mean? It means the `Mutex.Lock()` code is not great, and that you should find a way to accomplish this with communication instead.

Further, there's no need for a `RWMutex` in your code, a simpler `Mutex` would be better...

For "Communication" in go, you need a go routine to communicate with. The go-routine is linked to the `Broadcast` instance, and it's the only routine that knows the `Broadcast` state, and the only go-routine that can change that state.

Now, you just need to communicate state changes to/from that go-routine using channels.

In code, it would look like:

```
// Broadcast allows to send a signal to all listeners
type Broadcast struct {
    poke      chan bool
    receivers chan chan struct{}
    done      chan bool
}

// NewBroadcast creates a new broadcast
func NewBroadcast() *Broadcast {
    bc := &Broadcast{
        poke:      make(chan bool),
        receivers: make(chan chan struct{}),
        done:      make(chan bool),
    }
    go bc.listen()
    return bc
}

func (b *Broadcast) listen() {

    defer close(b.done)

    notify := make(chan struct{})
    for {
        select {
        case ok := <-b.poke:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            // all current receivers get a closed channel
            close(notify)
            // set up next batch of receivers.
            notify = make(chan struct{})
        case b.receivers <- notify:
            // great. A Receiver has our channel
        }
    }
}

// Close makes Broadcast implement the Closer interface
func (b *Broadcast) Close() error {
    select {
    case b.poke <- false:
    case <-b.done:
    }
    return nil
}

// Receive a channel on which the next (close) signal will be sent
func (b *Broadcast) Receive() <-chan struct{} {
    select {
    case r := <-b.receivers:
        return r
    case <-b.done:
        // FIXME - should probably return an error.
        return nil
    }
}

// Send a signal to all current Receivers
func (b *Broadcast) Send() {
    select {
    case b.poke <- true:
    case <-b.done:
        // FIXME - attempt to notify on a closed broadcaster... oops. Should probably return an error
    }
}
```

What's important in the above code? There is no `sync` usage, and there's a go-routine `listen()` for the `Broadcast` that manages the state. It listens for new Receivers and it listens for notification events. It is single-threaded, and as a consequence, it does not need any locking.

State changes are communicated via the `receiver`, `poke` and `done` channels.

Note that it now manages resources beyond the simple struct that it was, it's now got a go-routine you don't want to leak, so it should implement the `Close()` method, and you would do something like:

```
broadcaster := NewBroadcast()
defer broadcaster.Close()
```

It's very important to note that all the channels are unbuffered. This allows for a clean and reliable communication path, you can't have stale receivers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your implementation. I still find the use of locks (I agree that my use of `RWMutex` is overkill) easier, than having 2 additional channels and a goroutine. I could also implement a `Close` method in my original code, but as you mention `// FIXME - should probably return an error.`, it is then cumbersome to use (and some [official libs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker.Stop) never close their channel as well)